# User control not displaying values

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a user control with a few textboxes. I've created properties on the UC to set the textbox to those values.

On my page I have a placeholder inside a panel for the user control which I show as a popup. When I load the user control I set it's properties but when the popup shows none of the textboxes have their values set.

Not sure where I'm going wrong here, here's some code:

Page:

```
public void LoadFiguresControl()
{

    var mgr = new CompaniesBusinessManager();
    WebParts_CreateOwnershipFigures fig = (WebParts_CreateOwnershipFigures)Page.LoadControl("~/WebParts/CreateOwnershipFigures.ascx");
    if (ddlEditCompanies.SelectedValue != null && ddlEditCompanies.SelectedValue != "")
    {
        var cc = mgr.GetOwnershipCompanies(rlabs.letsema_re.Domain.CompanyQueries.GetOwnershipCompaniesType.By_Id, int.Parse(ddlEditCompanies.SelectedValue), -1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (cc != null)
        {

            fig.OwnershipCompanyId = cc.Id;
            fig.CompanyTitle = mgr.GetCompanies(cc.CompanyId.Value).FirstOrDefault().Name;
            fig.Shareholding = (cc.ShareholderPerc.HasValue ? cc.ShareholderPerc.Value : 0);
            fig.Black = (cc.BlackPerc.HasValue ? cc.BlackPerc.Value : 0);
            fig.RSA = (cc.RSAPerc.HasValue ? cc.RSAPerc.Value : 0);
        }
    }
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(fig);

}
```

A property example on the user control:

```
public string CompanyTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return lblOwnership.Text;

        }
        set
        {
            lblOwnership.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

And to show the popup:

```
   protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadFiguresControl();
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: show your Show() method ( 2nd one in btnEdit_Click )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using telerik controls with a WindowManager. It turns out that I can't use ajax modal popups with JavaScript unless I put them in a RadCodeBlock. After doing this everything worked as expected. I can't explain what's happening under the hood but this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the server click event of button. Which causes the postback to occur. Make sure you're properties which you're using to load the model popup are not getting reset. You can use `Page.IsPostBack` property to prevent it in Page_Load event.